# Submit form and a textarea on ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to submit a form and another textarea on my ajax post, will that be possible? Here is my code

```
<script>
function updateuseracc(form, password)
{   
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name="p";
    p.type="hidden";
    p.value=hex_sha512(password.value);
    password.value="";

    var email=$("#curemail").val();

    $.post('updateuser.php',$('#myform').serialize(),textarea:textarea),(function(data){
    });
}
</script>
```

I'm just getting errors with this

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If yes, please mark it as the answer so that others can see this.

Answer (score 1):

First textarea is not a variable. If you want to get the value of it do this:

```
var  text = $(textarea).text ();
```

Put data in curly braces, function is third parameter.

```
$.post('updateuser.php', {
            form:$('#myform').serialize(),
            textarea:text},
      function(data){
    //code...
});
```

In addition, you should take care of ANY security features on the server side!

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @user3196424 - Could you describe it's not working in greater detail? What error are you receiving? What do you expect to get back?