# Send form values through ajax to smtp mail form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smtp, sendmail

Email form not sending and can't figure out why. I used the advice form this post tp create the form. [Submit form and a textarea on ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357801/submit-form-and-a-textarea-on-ajax-post)

the reason for doing this is to greate a IE8 and 9 friendly form that works.

The on click function....

```
                $("form#example-advanced-form").click(function() {
                    //alert("submitting?");
                    // validate() just checks that required fields have values
                    //if (validate()) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'PHPMailer/sendMyform.php',
                             data: { name: $('#name').val(),
                                     from: $('#email').val(),
                                     subject: $('#role').val(),
                                     message: $('#coverletter').val()
                            },// end data
                            success: function clearFields() {
                                $('#name').val('');
                                $('#email').val('');
                            } // end success
                        }); // end ajax
                    /*}
                    else
                    {
                        var errmsg = "Your email could not be sent.<br />";
                        errmsg += "Please ensure that you've filled in all the fields.";
                        $(".errmsg").html(errmsg);
                        $(".errmsg").css("color", "#ff0000");
                    }*/
                    $('form#example-advanced-form').submit();
                }); // end click
```

The send mail form receiving the data...

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
    include("class.smtp.php");

    $email = new PHPMailer();

    try
    {
        //
        // Set server details for send
        //
        $email->IsSMTP();
        $email->Host = "****";
        $email->Port = 25;
        $email->SMTPAuth = true;
        $email->Username = "****";
        $email->Password = "****";



        //
        // Send mail from the contact form
        //
        $to = "****";
        $from = $_POST["email"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $subject = "From web: ".$_POST["role"];
        $message = $_POST["name"];

        $body = "<p>Hi,</p>";
        $body .= "<p>You have received a new query on your website.</p><p>Please see below:</p>";
        $body .= "<p>";
        $body .= str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $message);
        $body .= "</p>";
        $body .= "</body></html>";

        $email->SetFrom($from, $name);
        $email->AddReplyTo($from, $name);
        $email->AddAddress($to, $to);
        $email->Subject = $subject;
        $email->Body = $body;
        $email->IsHTML(true);

        $email->Send();

        session_start();
        $_SESSION["mailresult"] = "success";
        http_redirect("http://www.this.com");
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $_SESSION["mailresult"] = "failed";
        $_SESSION["mailerror"] = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I get a error Call to undefined function on line 49 which is...

```
            http_redirect("http://www.this.com");
```

Comment: Done **ANY** basic debugging, like checking the return value of the `->Send()` call? All of your code simply assumes nothing could ever fail, which is a very very very bad habit to get into.

Comment: how do return the value of send, my knowledge on this is beginner i'm afraid?

Comment: `$result = $mail->Send(); if ($result === false) { die($mail->ErrorInfo); }`

Comment: which file do i put this in?

Comment: can you tell me how to pas these two fields via ajax please, currently looks like this but as they are textarea and radio button the syntax i think is wrong thus it doesn't work...

'$('#coverletter').val(), //TEXT AREA
$('#workfor').val() //RADIO BUTTONS'